# Trying to send emails with Gmail API

Tags: python-3.x, api, email, google-api, gmail

I've been followning tutorials and reading articles trying to learn how to make sense of the gmail API using **python 3**.
I've gotten stuck on the messages.send method.

My authentication works but my CreateMessage function is throwing an error.

Here is my code so far:

```
def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):

      message = MIMEText(message_text)
      message['to'] = to
      message['from'] = sender
      message['subject'] = subject
      return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())}

    message = CreateMessage('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com','xxxxxxxx@gmail.com','subject','message text')
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    created_message = service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=message).execute()
```

The error it's throwing is "TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"
Any and all contrusctive criticism is welcome. Or any quality tutorials on the subject you can direct me to! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base64.urlsafe_b64encode` returns a `bytes` object. You should convert this to a string with `.decode("utf-8")`, which should fix your error.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is there a way to add any verification so gmail doesn't flag my emails as suspicious?

Comment: Ask that as a separate question